# upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 Server, do-release-upgrade still shows

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, motd

I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 13.04 Server a while ago. However, the notice that tells me there's a `New Release '13.04' available. Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.` still shows. Obviously, something somewhere went wrong, but everything is running fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` (on 12.04 and 10.04 systems that was `/var/lib/update-notifier/release-upgrade-available`). The release upgrade should have removed (or emptied) that file for you.

The `/etc/motd` file is updated by the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d`, this release upgrade part in particular by `/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade`. In there `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` (used to be `/usr/lib/update-manager/release-upgrade-motd`) is called, which checks if the file mentioned above (the stamp) exists. The latter script generates the stamp if not there and only updates the stamp if it is empty. It should probably update the stamp if the stamp is older than `/etc/lsb-release` (or something equivalent that gets written only during installation) as well.

Comment: That file doesn't exist. All I've got in there are: `dpkg-run-stamp`, `fsck-at-reboot`, `package-data-downloads` (empty folder), `updates-available` (which says how many package upgrades are available, no mention of release upgrades), and `user.d`, another empty folder.

Comment: Contents of `/etc/lsb-release`: `DISTRIB=Ubuntu`, `DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04`, `DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring`, `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=Ubuntu 13.04`

Comment: @NickRutten I tried this out on an upgrade of 10.10 to 12.04, I assumed things would be the same on 13.04 (which I currently do not run). Maybe the update of `/etc/motd` got changed. On 12.04 is a link to `/var/run/motd` which gets generated on every login. Can you see if that file (`var/run/motd`) got generated on last login to the system?

Comment: Yes, it did, timestamp is matching the time I logged into my box.

Comment: Do you have something with `release-upgrade` in the name in `/etc/update-motd.d/`? If so look in there what is actually called to do the work.

Comment: Got it, they moved the file to `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`. Removed it, got rid of the notification. Thanks for your help figuring this out!

Comment: I will update my answer thanks for the feedback.